# Windows Batch file to start multiple services in sequence

Tags: windows, service, command-line

I need to create a batch file to start a handful of Windows services, which need to start in a certain order. Also the last three services can only start when the service previous has started up (can take about 30 seconds for this to happen).

I was going to use `SC START <SERVIVENAME>`

How can I make the last three servies wait until the previous has started?

Comment: Why not configure the (apparent) dependencies between the services and then just start the final services that you want running?

Comment: or the old `net start "some service"` is synchronous

Comment: NET START/STOP looks like the way to go, never realised it was synchronous